# How to correct R syntax for summing two fields?

Tags: r, dbase

In a dbf I make the new field xyz then attempt to sum existing item1 and item2 fields and replace field xyz with sum and then create a new dbf-- but does not work. All working without the for loop.  I hope someone can help.  Thank you.

```
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/temp")
dbfdata <- read.dbf("sldu_500ka.dbf", as.is = TRUE)
dbfdata$xyz <- 1:nrow(dbfdata)
for(i in 1:nrow(dbfdata)) {
     row <- dbfdata[i,]
     dbfdata$xyz <- dbfdata$item1 + dbfdata$item2  
  }
write.dbf(dbfdata, "sldu_500k1.dbf")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **reproducible example** that includes some sample data, for example with `dput(head(dbfdata,10))`    And as a first hint: no need for a loop here!

Comment: You've already got what you need. Ditch everything but `dbfdata$xyz <- dbfdata$item1 + dbfdata$item2`.

Comment: As others have already stated: Just don't use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly, but

```
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/temp")
dbfdata <- read.dbf("sldu_500ka.dbf", as.is = TRUE)
dbfdata$xyz <- dbfdata$item1 + dbfdata$item2  
write.dbf(dbfdata, "sldu_500k1.dbf")
```

should do the job. Instead of looping overall rows, you can add the entire column at once.

Comment: Thank you. removing the loop results in the following error: <pre>
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/temp")
dbfdata <- read.dbf("sldu_500ka.dbf", as.is = TRUE)
dbfdata$xyz <- dbfdata$item1 + dbfdata$item2  
--> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "xyz", value = numeric(0)) : 
-->  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8
## overwrite the file with this new copy
write.dbf(dbfdata, "sldu_500k1.dbf")

Comment: If my solution doesn't work, you really need to add the output of `dput(head(dbfdata,10))` to your question